# How to get Ether in Ethereum Wallet test network?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

How can I get some ether to deploy a smart contract when using a test network (like Ropsten, or Rinkeby) in Ethereum Wallet ? Because at the beginning when creating a new account, I have `0.00 ether` like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There you go...
For Rinkeby: https://faucet.rinkeby.io/ 
For Ropsten: http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying the first link. It seems that it works. However the second link, it doesn't work on my machine. Does it work on your machine ?

Comment: Yes, I just requested 1 ether and got it. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x5b700c5da7f01e103e05422bab5c63c268dd87d978125a8f31484136e0a49e7f

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work on my machine :((